# The letter 'W' gets rendered oddly

Tags: google-chrome

It seems that with this particular font (it's one of the Ubuntu fonts; I can't tell which one exactly because Chrome's debugger doesn't tell me which font-family won the CSS battle) the letter 'W' (both cases), at the default zoom level and typically with smaller sizes, will render very oddly: (open the image in a new tab)

[image]

The right-hand side of the letter is totally wrong. Changing the zoom levels will mitigate (but not eliminate) the issue.

Does anyone know how to fix this? It doesn't happen on Firefox or IE so I assume it's not an issue with the font itself.

Comment: It is specifically the `Ubuntu` font in the CSS; I'm seeing the same thing.

Comment: If you are unhappy with this font, you are free to use another.

Comment: @mdpc: The choice is made by the website designers, not by the user; and the problem is likely not with the font itself but the way Chrome on Windows renders it.

Comment: It looks the same on Firefox -- it's just the way that font is.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It doesn't look the same when I access the page on Firefox. http://imgur.com/lmWXU

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch -- I suspect it has to do with kerning.  When the letter is adjacent to a space it's rendered differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known hinting problem: visit https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+bug/801716 for the bug report.